# Передать значение boolean с одного Activity в другое Activity

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Каким образом можно из одного Activity передать булево значение в другое Activity? К примеру:

```
boolean playPause = false;
```

Во втором Activity его прочитать и изменить значение `boolean` на переданное? Если возможно, пример кода.

**Обновление**

Если я правильно понимаю то "ловить" переданный `Intent` мне нужно в `onCreate`, но возникает ошибка - строка

```
boolean addedToFavorites = passedDate.getBoolean("addedToFavorites");
```

Подчёркнута красным ошибка

> (not a statement)

А  `playPause` в  `boolean playPause` неактивно. Если

```
{ 
    boolean playPause = passedDate.getBoolean("playPause");
}
```

Беру в скобки то подчёркивание исчезает, но `boolean playPause` по прежнему не активно - `Variable "playPause" is never used`. Как это исправить? Прошу прощение за глупый вопрос, я только начал изучать java и android.

Comment: если мое решение вам помогло, то отметьте его как ответ, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Я не очень понял что и где вы получаете. Скиньте свой onCreate во втором активити и кусок, где вы вызываете его. Посмотрим что не так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Элементарно. Когда стартуете активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("playPause", false);
startActivity(intent)
```

Затем, чтобы получить это значение, в другом активити:

```
Bundle passedDate = getIntent().getExtras();
if(passedDate != null)
    boolean playPause = passedDate.getBoolean("playPause");
```

Не забудьте, что получать данные вы должны по тому же ключу, что и передали. То есть, если у вас `Intent.putExtra("playPause", value)"`, то и получать вы должны `passedDate.getBoolean("playPause")`

Comment: Если вызов осуществляется из активити, вместо `getBaseContext()` будет более уместен банальный `this`

Comment: @pavloff, вы правы

Comment: Прошу прощения. Конечно же вместо addedToFavorites - playPause. Но это я некоректно на форуме написал, а проблема осталась. Вот код TwoActivity: 'public class TwoActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
   
    boolean playPause = false;

 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);

        Bundle passedDate = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(passedDate != null)
            boolean playPause = passedDate.getBoolean("playPause");}'

Comment: @Сергей ой, ой, такое очень трудно прочитать. Отредактируйте лучше свой вопрос, добавив туда эти строчки. Ну и отформатируйте правильно, конечно.

Comment: @Rishka Огромное спасибо за помощь! Разобрался.