# Почему значение переменной не меняется из метода?

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь передать измененную в методе (Open) переменную abc и получить её в другом классе . Я всегда получаю переменную  в виде www.google.com ( то есть не измененную. )

Почему она не не меняется в в методе (Open) ???

.

```
  MainActivity2_2 myClass = new  MainActivity2_2();
             String loadUrl = myClass.abc;
```

.

```
 public class MainActivity2_2 extends AppCompatActivity {


        public String abc=("www.google.com");

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2_2);


        }

        public  void  Open(View view ){

            abc="http://vk.com";

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2_3.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
```

Comment: Думаю потому, что вы пытаетесь получить ее значение раньше, чем она изменится в методе Open, то есть раньше, чем этот самый Open вызовится

Comment: Потому что данные между активностями нужно передавать через интент. См. ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424891/11515

Comment: Могу ли я использовать  SharedPreferences?

Comment: использовать активити, как в первом куске кода нельзя. точнее вы можете, но работать это точно не будет. активити компонент жизненного цикла, который создает система, клиентские экземпляры активити "мертвые". для передачи данных между активити используется интент