# Передать String путь из одного Activity в другое

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Пересылаю разными, что нашел, способами String path из FragmentActivity в MainActivity, а в MainActivity всё равно null. В чем моя ошибка?
**FragmentActivity**:

```
Intent intentPath;
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
@Override
public void PickiTonCompleteListener(String path) {
    if (mainActivity.file1 == 1) {
        intentPath = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intentPath.putExtra("pathFile1", path); // первый вариант попытки передать path
        mainActivity.FilePath1 = path; // второй вариант попытки передать path
    }
    ...
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
@Override
public void PickiTonCompleteListener(String path) {
    if (file1 == 1) {
        FilePath1 = path; // здесь всегда получается null (попытка: mainActivity.FilePath1 = path;)
        FilePath = FilePath1;
        System.out.println(pathGetFile2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("pathFile2")); // здесь всегда получается null (попытка: intentPath.putExtra("pathFile1", path);)
    }
    ...
}
```

Изначально задача составляет передать путь (path) из FragmentActivity в MainActivity для последующей обработки пути в мэйн активити

Comment: Вы что-то странное делаете очень неправильно... Создавать активити вручную - нет смысла - никогда так не делайте. Посмотрите тут как передавать данные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424886/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-boolean-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-activity-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-activity?rq=1

Comment: Другое FragmentActivity у меня создано по другой причине, на ней view pager, а из фрагментов view pager'a хочу передать значение path в мэйн активити. Сейчас посмотрю вашу ссылку, спасибо

Comment: Это можно по разному сделать. Надо только иметь в виду, что в один момент может существовать только одна активити. Та, куда вы хотите данные передать - не существует. Исходите из этого. Возможно, вам нужен startActivityForResult (который, правда, уже deprecated)

Comment: Вот пытался я и с помощью startActivityForResult, но ругается на android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
Как сделал: вызвал в фрагмент активити метод мэйна через mainActivity.метод, а в этом методе в мэйне уже есть startActivityForResult

Comment: Очень странная ошибка. Покажите код который не работает описанным образом - может кто то вам подскажет в чем дело

Comment: Какую бы вы себе причину не придумали, но нельзя написать *MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity()* и думать, что это будет работать. Активити может создать только система через Intent (в манифесте приложения или через метод startActivity()),  иначе это будет "мертвый" пользовательский класс, а не системный контроллер

Comment: @Xelloeuy *вызвал в фрагмент активити метод мэйна через mainActivity.метод* - хороший пример того, как делать нельзя ни в коем случае. У любой активности есть метод `startActivityForResult` - не надо за ним лезть в другую. И в принципе им нужно **ЗАПУСКАТЬ** активность, из которой хотим что-то получить, а не вызывать из неё самой.  Дать вам конкретный ответ невозможно, поскольку мы не знаем структуру и логику вашего приложения - в какой последовательности и при каких условиях запускаются и закрываются активности, при каких условиях передаются данные и в каком направлении. Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего из-за того что FilePath1 у MainActivity не является статическим полем, данные передаются в другой объект который создаётся в самом фрагменте.

Я сам новичок но могу посоветовать вам использовать ViewModel из Architecture Components для хранения общих данных, либо как вариант можно обратиться к Activity из Framgent - во фрагменте это можно сделать через requireActivity()

вариант с обращением к Activity из Fragment:

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).PickiTonCompleteListener("your_string)
```

вариант с ViewModel:

Класс ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){
    val FilePath1 = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

класс MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    val vm: MyViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // other your code
        observer()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    private fun observer(){
        vm.FilePath1.observe(this, Observer<String> {
            //give your data from fragment
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: У него ничего не работает, потому что активити, созданная через `new MainActivity()` и не должна работать. Никакие способы передачи данных не заставят такую активити "жить"