# Как передать переменую в activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как передать данные и отобразить их в уже созданном однажды Activity? Если использовать startActivity(intent), то оно каждый раз создаёт новое Activity.
Пример: У меня есть activity которое отображаеться на єкранє. Мне нужно при каком-то условие передать новое значение переменой в activity и при этом поменять фон activity взависимости от значения этой переменой к примеру, не создавай новоё activity.

Comment: Используй глобальные переменные. В `MainActivity` объявляй `public static int Val` (ну или String, что надо), а в остальных пиши в импорте `import static your_package.MainActivity.Val;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передать значение boolean с одного Activity в другое Activity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424886/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-boolean-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-activity-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-activity)

Comment: Или, если нужно чтобы потом фон всегда оставался таким же, можно сохранять значение в sharedpreferences, на втором экране смотришь что там сохранено и меняешь соответственно фон

Answer (score 0):

Присвойте id вашему layout или imageView  и меняйте исходя из условия.

в xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

в java

```
if(i == 1 ) {
  LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.layout_bg);
  ll.setBackground(R.drawable.file);
}
```

грубый пример